# Is it forbidden to enter a church for non-religious reason

Tags: halacha

I was taught in NY at Kevelson (an orthodox synagogue in Brooklyn) in the 60's that it is forbidden to enter a church.  Out here in Illinois, our election place is in a local church.  I'm wondering, according to orthodox halacha, whether it is אסור to go in for that secular reason, or whether it is just discouraged.

Comment: Perhaps we should merge back this way? The current master question is rather weak. Not sure why it got so many votes.